# Database Connection Pooling in Java Servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, oracle11g

I'm creating a web application for Employee Management System, using: Apache Tomcat as HTTP Server, Oracle as the database, Applets for the client side programming and Servlets for server side programming. I also want to use DBCP to manage connections to the database.

I would like the servlet performing queries to use the username and password entered by the client for the connection. But so far I've seen that the username and password for the connection pool must be set when configuring the resource in `context.xml`.

Is there any way to achieve this and still use DBCP? Or will I have to open connections in `doGet()` and `doPost()` for every request?

Comment: Why would the client provide its own credentials to access to the database? What's your motivation here?

Comment: you can create your own connection pool and store in the servlet contet to be reused by the requests.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza The client must provide username and password for verification; a servlet checks if such a user exists and allows them to perform queries/updates on the database.

Comment: @Zielu Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Your use case seems more like a login rather than a direct database user validation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What would be the difference between the two?

Comment: You could validate the user credentials against a table in your database or another security mechanism like LDAP and still have a single database user that will execute the database operations. By this, you only manage a single database user. In your proposed solution (database user per application user), you may create several database connections per user in the application and consume more resources in server side.

Comment: Normally there is one DB user for your application (servlets) and there is a special table in your DB that stores the users of your applications (not the DB users just your application). The DB connection is done using always the same 'DB user', but then the users credentials are checked against this special aplication user table.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It's a login. I hadn't considered multiple connections per user. But still, how could I provide different username and password for each user for a connection taken from the pool?

Comment: In the strange case you need to use different users to access to the same database, just create/configure another database connection pool. You could also create database connection pools programatically, but you should only do this when necessary, and your current problem doesn't need this.

Comment: @Zielu But if I make only one DB user and all connections are made using this user, I would be unable to tell who made which changes in the database. Also, this would mean that any user of the application is not restricted by the roles/privileges they have been granted in the database.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But if I access the database using only one connection, I cannot tell who made which changes to the database. Also, this would mean that any user of the application is not restricted by the roles/privileges they have been granted in the database (if they manage to get past the servlet used for making queries/operations).

Comment: That's why you need additional fields in the tables to store the name of the user who made a change and the date and time he/she did. Also, you could have an audit log system and use triggers or aspects to log the proper audit info in these tables before any successful insert/update/delete in any of your tables.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well that's one problem down. But how do I restrict access to certain tables and privileges for certain users, since for single user connection the user must have the superset of privileges of all possible application users?

Comment: You define roles for the authenticated users in your app and then validate if the user has the autorization to access or modify a resource. And keep using a single database user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, normally, the restriction logic is done on the application side not the DataBase side.

But if you want really to use the DB security model then you need to create seperate DataSource (ConnectionPool) for each logged user and store it in its session. If you have many concurrent access you will soon discover that you are running out of the resources.

For example I am using DataSource as it is easier to configure but you may just use any connection pool implementation.

In the login action you create new DataSource, (for example using apache common: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) and you insert into the session

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
...
ds.setPassword(userPassword);
ds.setUserName(login);
...

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("DBcon",ds);
```

and in your other gets/posts:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)session.getAttribute("DBcon");
```

Since it is going to be one DataSource per user, make sure you use some low parameteres of the pool, for example size=3, as it should be enough for a user.

Answer (score 0):

## `DataSource::getConnection​(String username, String password)`

The `DataSource` interface has a method expressly for your purpose: Varying the name and password for each connection while using the all the other previously set options for connecting: [`DataSource::getConnection​(String username, String password)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

The `java.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` interface carries the same kind of method, [`getPooledConnection​(String user, String password)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html#getPooledConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). So your particular connection pooling implementation may support this.

```
public javax.sql.DataSource obtainDataSource() {
    org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource() ;
    dataSource("AcmeInvoices database data source") ;
    source.setServerName( "localhost" ) ;
    source.setDatabaseName( "invoicing" ) ;
    // source.setUser( "Scott" ) ;
    // source.setPassword( "tiger" ) ;
    return dataSource ;  // Returning a reference to the object of this concrete class `PGSimpleDataSource` as an object of the interface `DataSource`. 
}
```

When doing some database work:

```
Connection conn = myDataSource.getConnection( "Scott" , "tiger" ) ;
… run SQL
conn.close() ;  // Or better yet: Use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close the connection.
```

For more discussion, see [an Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56318275/642706) on a related Question.

See Oracle [Tutorial on `DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html).